# Drupal 7 custom CKeditor configuration

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, ckeditor, wysiwyg

Can anybody suggest a way to setup a custom configuration for the CKEeditor in Drupal using the WYSIWYG module.

The end result I'm looking for is to enable the Tableresize plugin and clear the table default values (border/width etc).

Answer (score 0):

This is not a good method to solve the ploblem, but it work for me.
In file wysiwyg\editors\ckeditor.inc change this

```
if (!empty($extra_plugins)) {
  $settings['extraPlugins'] = implode(',', $extra_plugins);
}
```

to

```
$extra_plugins[] = 'tableresize';
if (!empty($extra_plugins)) {
  $settings['extraPlugins'] = implode(',', $extra_plugins);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. It may come in handy, but as you said, it's not ideal.

Answer (score 0):

In Drupal we can install themes,
Extend -Install new module
You can install by two days through URL or by uploading the tar.gz file you can install CKE editor